# How to call page from mainpage in silver light using visual studio

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have created one page in silver light using visual studio, now i want it call from silver light mainpage on button click , how would i get it ...

Comment: Meaning you want to call somepage.XAML from MainPage.xaml on button click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SelectionPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```